# statistics of sessions with gap-and-island problem

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am investigating the problem of gap-and-island in a log table, matching it with another table to give statistics of sessions with that problem.

Table1: `labels` table containing the mode of travel used in a session.

```sql
REATE TABLE labels(user_id INT, session_id INT,
  start_time TIMESTAMP,mode TEXT);

INSERT INTO labels (user_id,session_id,start_time,mode)
VALUES  (48,652,'2016-04-01 00:47:00+01','foot'),
(9,656,'2016-04-01 00:03:39+01','car'),(9,657,'2016-04-01 00:26:51+01','car'),
(9,658,'2016-04-01 00:45:19+01','car'),(46,663,'2016-04-01 00:13:12+01','car')
```

Table2: raw sessions' logs stored in `raw_data`  table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE raw_data(session_id INT,timestamp TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO raw_data(session_id,timestamp)          
VALUES (652,'2016-04-01 00:46:11.638+01'),(652,'2016-04-01 00:47:00.566+01'),
       (652,'2016-04-01 00:48:06.383+01'),(656,'2016-04-01 00:14:17.707+01'),
       (656,'2016-04-01 00:15:18.664+01'),(656,'2016-04-01 00:16:19.687+01'),
       (656,'2016-04-01 00:24:20.691+01'),(656,'2016-04-01 00:25:23.681+01'),
       (657,'2016-04-01 00:24:50.842+01'),(657,'2016-04-01 00:26:51.096+01'),
       (657,'2016-04-01 00:37:54.092+01')
```

I want to search each session for to find those having time difference between 2 consecutive rows greater than 5-minutes.

- I will then report these sessions together with their corresponding `mode`.
- I will also give the total number of sessions having the problem.

Note: here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vPVY-bnd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select session_id     
      ,timestamp    
      ,user_id  
      ,start_time   
      ,count(diff) over()/2 as number_of_session_with_problem
from  (
       select *
              ,case when timestamp-lag(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp)    > '00:05:00.000' then 1 when lead(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) - timestamp > '00:05:00.000' then 1 end as diff
       from   raw_data join labels using(session_id)
      ) t
where diff = 1
```

| session_id | timestamp | user_id | start_time | number_of_session_with_problem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 656 | 2016-04-01 00:16:19.687 | 9 | 2016-04-01 00:03:39 | 2 |
| 656 | 2016-04-01 00:24:20.691 | 9 | 2016-04-01 00:03:39 | 2 |
| 657 | 2016-04-01 00:26:51.096 | 9 | 2016-04-01 00:26:51 | 2 |
| 657 | 2016-04-01 00:37:54.092 | 9 | 2016-04-01 00:26:51 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eR5f5AOQ)

Comment: Where are the rows repeated, please?